# Python Twisted Connect never triggering

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, twisted

I have an console type application written in Python that is meant to trigger a remote connect, the actual connect is never being triggered.

Here is a cut down version of the application:

```
import sys
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads, protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

host = 'localhost'
port = 8080

class InterfaceFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return protocol()

def ConnectToMaster():
    deferItem = endpoint.connect(factory)
    deferItem.addErrback(ConnectFailed)
    print('Connecting to master')

def MainProcessLoop():
    done = False

    while True:
        if done == False:
            print 'Triggered connect'
            reactor.callLater(0.1, ConnectToMaster)
            done = True
        time.sleep(1)

def ConnectFailed(self, reason):
    print('Failed to connect... : reason of {0}'.format(reason))

endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port)
protocol = LineReceiver()
factory = InterfaceFactory()

reactor.callFromThread(MainProcessLoop)
reactor.run()
```

The output is:

```
$  python testCode.py 
Triggered connect
```

I am really confused as this should be Twisted 101...  The MainProcessLoop is in a thread, but from it's a thread that is managed by Twisted, plus reactor.run() isn't in any form of thread.

Does it matter that the MainProcessLoop is in a loop and can block?  In reality there is a get_input() in there, but chopped it out for code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> The MainProcessLoop is in a thread

As far your example is concerned, `MainProcessLoop` is not in any thread. `reactor.callFromThread` doesn't spawn any thread, it assumes your executing from a thread and you want something to run in the reactor thread.

> Does it matter that the MainProcessLoop is in a loop and can block?

Yes it matters since `MainProcessLoop` isn't actually in a thread. This is also the reason why you are not connecting to anything. The function blocks and the Twisted reactor never gets the chance to run tasks.

Hopefully that answers those questions. Now for the solution and it should just be 2 small changes. First change `reactor.callFromThread(MainProcessLoop)` to `reactor.callInThread(MainProcessLoop)` this will spawn a thread and run the function.

Next change `reactor.callLater(0.1, ConnectToMaster)` to

```
reactor.callFromThread(reactor.callLater, 0.1, ConnectToMaster)
```

As for the `while` loop in your example, I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, but whatever it is you should consider using Twisted's event loop, even if the while loop is in a thread.

Comment: Why should reactor.callLater(0.1, ConnectToMaster) be changed to reactor.callFromThread(reactor.callLater, 0.1, ConnectToMaster) please?

Comment: Because you're attempting to do `reactor` dependent things in a thread and the `reactor` isn't thread safe. `callFromThread` will run functions in the "main" thread, which in your case where you wish to connect to servers, is what you want.